# Encrypting a JDEC file in Lattice MachxO2

Tags: fpga, encryption, lattice

I am working on lattice MachxO2 FPGA. Our customer is asking to  to encrypt the JDEC file (the bit file). How do I do this?

There is sample Unencrypted JDEC file and some information [given here](http://www.latticesemi.com/documents/TN1204.pdf) from p.no 35 onward, but it does not mention of encrypting the same.

Answer (score 1):

The Lattice Diamond 2.1 help for bitgen on command line says this is only available for LatticeECP2S and LatticeXP2 devices. Look for bitgen -e -k and -s options.
Maybe running these options on MachXO2 device works...

Answer (score 1):

From the [product info](http://www.latticesemi.com/products/cpld/machxo2/security.cfm) it would appear that encryption is not supported. You can lock the device against readback, though.